# Resource not found error when accessing wcf svc file from remote machine

Tags: wcf, iis-7, wcf-hosting

I hosted a simple wcf service in IIS and I am able to access it from the IIS server machine without any issues. But, when I access it from any other machine I get the error:
 `"Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found."` I put an aspx file in the same location as that of the svc file and is accessible from all the machines; to rule out the connectivity problems. Please throw your thoughts on this.

Comment: Are you able to access the .svc file from the other machine?

Answer (score -1):

It can be deployment or configuration issue. It can related to MIME type.
So plese re check your deployement process.

Refer the below links:

1. [Host WCF Service on IIS 7 & Windows Server 2008](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx)
2. [Setting up a netTcpBinding enabled WCF Service in IIS 7](http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2010/10/08/setting-up-a-nettcpbinding-enabled-wcf-service-in-iis-7.aspx)